# Getting error specifically when using <v-file-unput>

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using `VueJS` with `vuetify`. I have an input tag and button which triggers function `@click`, once I change to `v-file-input` component I get an error.

Here is the code - script and template:

```js
<script>
import papa from "papaparse";
export default {
  name: "CompareInput",
  data() {
    return {
      csvData: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    csvToJson() {
      let csvFile = this.$refs.file.files[0];
      if (csvFile == undefined) {
        alert("Please select a file to convert");
        this.csvData = [];
        return;
      }
      papa.parse(csvFile, {
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        preview: 100,
        complete(result) {
          this.csvData = result.data;
          for (let item of this.csvData) {
            console.log(item.input_fullName);
          }
          console.log(this.csvData);
        },
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <h3>CSV Parser</h3>

    <v-file-input multiple ref="file" type="file"> </v-file-input>
    <v-btn @click="csvToJson" class="primary">Submit</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>
```

The error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Again, everything works fine with the regular input tag.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you misunderstood [@JenifferJin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70324315/9275224).

Your error is on this line:

```
let csvFile = this.$refs.file.files[0];
```

You are referencing `v-file-input` component, but trying to work with it as with native HTML `input` tag. This should not be done.

`v-file-input` does not contain **files** field directly. You can see this for yourself if you write something like this and look into browser console:

```
...
csvToJson() {
  console.log(this.$refs.file)
  ...
}
...
```

When you are working with `v-file-input`, you should use **v-model** to store your file (or files).

So the answer is:

```
<v-file-input
  v-model="filesModel"
  multiple
  type="file">
</v-file-input>
...
data() {
  return {
    filesModel: [],
  };
},
...
methods: {
  csvToJson() {
    if (this.filesModel === null 
        || this.filesModel === undefined 
        || this.filesModel.length === 0) {
        alert("Please select a file to convert");
        return;
    }
    let csvFile = this.filesModel[0];
    ...the rest of your code
  },
},
```

[There's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/dyVOgpG) that may help you to understand the difference between `v-file-input` and `input`.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation, I get the problem now and made it work with multiple files and the rest of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my experience:

```
<v-file-input
    show-size counter
    accept="video/*"
    v-model="video"
    @change="onVideo"
>
</v-file-input>
```

in methods of Vue.js:

```
onVideo: function () {
    console.log(this.video)
}
```

Comment: Still having the same problem...

Comment: What version of Vue.js are you using?

Comment: The current version of Vuetify does not support Vue 3

Comment: Vuetify- 2.6.1
Vue- 2.6.14

Comment: You should remove <v-btn> button.

Comment: v-file-input should be triggered with @change function such as my code.

Comment: <onVideo> of my code is <csvToJson> of your one.

Comment: Tried your suggestions still getting this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')